# Compare sysdate with iso 8601 using oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, timestamp, sysdate

The problem is that I am currently trying  to resolve is to select a date time value (iso 8601) and compare it with the sysdate and time, and the sysdate/time has to be 20 min in the past.

I have tried using `TO_TIMESTAMP` and tried to convert the `SYSDATE` but the problem keeps returning.

```
select * from table 
where timestamp_from_the_table > to_date(systimestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3TZR') -INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
```

The result I would like is to have a list with the timestamps from table but filtered with the time only from 20 min in the past not longer.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you call `TO_DATE(...)` on a value which is already a `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`)?

Comment: the reason I do that is because I have to convert systimestamp to iso 8601 to compare it. I think I am not sure if I need to do that.

Comment: What is the data type of column `timestamp_from_the_table`?

Comment: The value comes as a Varchar(35). So the data type of the column is varchar

Answer (score 0):

Never store date values as string, i.e. `VARCHAR2`!

In your case you can run

```
WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(timestamp_from_the_table, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3TZR') 
       > systimestamp - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
```

It might be an option to create a virtual column, i.e.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD (real_timestamp TIMESTAMP(3) WITH TIME ZONE (TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(timestamp_from_the_table, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3TZR') ));
```

Then you could simply run

```
WHERE real_timestamp > systimestamp - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
```

Comment: when I use your first command I get ORA-01882: timezone region not found error